# Pass a variable from one method to another

Tags: php, variables

I'm having trouble passing a variable from one method to another, I'm trying as follows, but failed

ddsd

```
    public function hacerloginAction(){    
    //Obtener parámetros
    $v_c_request    = $this->getRequest();
    $a_params       = $v_c_request->getParams();


    $v_c_url                = Zend_Registry::get('base_action')."login/hacerlogin";
    $this->view->v_c_url    = $v_c_url;

    //Realizar autentificación OpenId - Parte 1: conectar_openid

        //p_c_parametros 
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace("/p_c_parametros", "", dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
        //Si 'a_params["p_c_parametros"]' tiene valores se asignan a una variable de sesion
        if( isset($a_params["p_c_parametros"]) && $a_params["p_c_parametros"] != null){
            $_SESSION['p_c_parametros'] = $a_params["p_c_parametros"];
        }

        //Se obtienen el parametro de 'p_openid' hya.com.mx
        $p_openid = str_replace("|","/",$a_params["p_openid"]);
        $this->obj_openidlog->conectar_openid($p_openid);

    //Render a la página de inicio.
    $this->render("formalogin");
}
```

ds

Comment: This... Is a drastic change from the original exampled code.. You should have included this first, this is why you have got a load of information which is of no use to you

Comment: It's basically the same example, others can get to the answer to this, if only changes in the variables etc...

Comment: Well, the updated code changes the usage and reasons to why you are not getting correct validations

Comment: Who can help me, what happens is that I just this poregunta banearon. that I can do?

Comment: I have given you an answer below, read it and reply to my comments for clarification

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was helpful, but I wanted the ban removed please as hereby learn enough.

Comment: Which ban are you speaking about?

Comment: I get this message when trying to ask a question -> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: This is a ban which cannot be manually lifted, the way to remove this ban is to contribute back to the community, giving answers which receive reputation and/or get marked as the answer to the question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get output of "success" quite simply, the following code will produce the desired output:

```
class myclass{
    public $global;
    public function method_one(){
        $this->global = "succes";
    }

    public function method_two(){
        return $this->global;
    }
}

$Class = new myclass();

$Class->method_one();
echo $Class->method_two();
```

As `global` is set to blank by default, you will have to call `method_one();` to give the internal variable a value. Only then you would beable to produce an echo.

Otherwise, the following:

```
$Class = new myclass();


var_dump($Class->method_two());
```

produces

> NULL

---

On a side note. I'd recommend avoiding the use of reserved PHP words such as `global` as it could create alot of confusion later on in the development [Use of Global scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

---

**With your updated code**

The reason you are not getting the expected validations is this little line here:

```
 header("Location: http://hyapresenta.com/sv3/public/login/obtener");
```

since you are calling your first method to set the variable.. You are also causing a page redirect, which is resetting all your changes prior to this (this is because your defaults are loaded on pageload), You could look into using sessions to keep your changes past page refreshes. Only downside is that it'll require a drastic structure change

Comment: There is no way to redirect and show courage?

Comment: @user3680708 Sorry for the delay. *show courage* care to explain?

Comment: Understood, perhaps did not know me well but explain and his proposal was understood Friend

Answer (score 1):

`$global` should be inside the class. You have it outside.

```
class myclass{

      public $global;

      public function method_one(){
             $this->global = "succes";
      }

      public function method_two(){
             return $this->global;
      }
}
```

Comment: now try putting it in the class, but still not working.

Comment: @user3680708, Probably because you are not using the class correctly later in the code. Why not include in your question the code where you use the class?

Comment: @ rob look at my update

Answer (score 1):

To access a variable with `$this->`, it needs to be a class property:

```
class myclass{
    public $global;

    public function method_one(){
        $this->global = "succes";
    }

    public function method_two(){
        return $this->global;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a shared variable, it could be an attribute:

```
class myclass{

  private $variable;

  public function method_one(){
         $this->variable = "success";
  }

  public function method_two(){
         return $this->variable;
  }
}
```

Every instance of myclass will have its own private copy of the variable.

You can use this code to test it:

```
$myObject = new myclass();

$myObject->method_one();
echo $myObject->method_two();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but still not working: (

Comment: @user3680708, I added some example code to my answer, so you can test it. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

"$this" is used to access class's inside variable. You can see the details here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
your code must be like

```
class myclass{
      public $global;
      public function method_one(){
             $this->global = "succes";
      }

      public function method_two(){
             return $this->global;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276505/rob) said, your issue was with the scope of the global variable.

```js
class myclass{
    public $global;

    public function method_one(){
        $this->global = "succes";
    }

    public function method_two(){
        return $this->global;
    }
}
```

I encourage you to spend a couple of minutes to study the concept of scopes throughly, as it is an imperative concept of modern programming languages.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/3764424) is a great resource to do so. (Don't mind the fact it's in Javascript)